# How to run two queries with the second query using the results from the first

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have tried looking this up, but i am not sure if my terminology is correctly.
My initial query works fine, however i want to do a calculation based on the results from the first query.
Its not possible to do this from the initial query due to the Inner Joins and Group By

I can accomplish this by saving this Query as a View and running my second query against the view. But this is not ideal for the usage.

What is the correct wording for using two queries in such a way, the second using the results from the first.

Example:

```
Select, column1, column2, column3, column4, SUM(column5) as column5, SUM(column6) as column6, TableB.column7
From TableA 
Left Out Join TableB 
on TableB.column7 = TableA.column1
Group By column1, column2, column3, column4

Select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,
(ISNULL (NULLIF(column5 - column6,0) / NULLIF(column5,0),0)  * 100)  else 0 end as columnGP
from (Previous Query just ran)
```

How can i store the results as a Variable, how long is the Data held as a variable? I storing as a variable will have a knock on effect from a performance side

Comment: You'll need to `INSERT` the data from the first query into a table. That might be staging table, a (local) temporary table, or even a table variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the first query as a sub-query in the second one

```sql
Select
    column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,
    (ISNULL (NULLIF(column5 - column6,0) / NULLIF(column5,0),0)  * 100)  else 0 end as columnGP
from (
    Select, column1, column2, column3, column4, SUM(column5) as column5, SUM(column6) as column6, TableB.column7
    From TableA 
    Left Out Join TableB 
    on TableB.column7 = TableA.column1
    Group By column1, column2, column3, column4
) x
```

To do this enclose the sub-query in braces and give it an alias acting as a table name (here `x`).

I just copied your queries; however, there seems to be a syntax error in them. `else 0 end` looks like the end of a missing case-expression.

But you can do the calculation in a single query

```sql
Select
    column1, column2, column3, column4,
    SUM(column5) as sum_column5, SUM(column6) as sum_column6,
    TableB.column7,
    CASE WHEN SUM(column5) = 0
      THEN 0
      ELSE (SUM(column5) - SUM(column6)) / SUM(column5) * 100
    END AS columnGP
From
    TableA
    Left Outer Join TableB
        on TableB.column7 = TableA.column1
Group By
    column1, column2, column3, column4, TableB.column7
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i missed the end of the statement 'else 0 end as [Margin%]' 
it was a quick free type, i didnt think posting the long query was beneficial with meaningless column names, I can edit my original post and include the query.

Comment: My Bad, you hit the nail on the head, your second method is the same as my method, however it was not working because of a missing groupby clause for column 5 and 6. It was because my ELSE (Calculation) DId not contain a SUM. Re-reading your query validated that. updated and confirmed it worked thanks

Comment: All SELECTED columns not being aggregated must be listed in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Make nested query. So instead of two queries, do one query where "Previous Query just run" is replaced with first query

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3, 
       column4, 
       column5, 
       column6,
       (ISNULL (NULLIF(column5 - column6,0) / NULLIF(column5,0),0)  * 100)  else 
       0 end as columnGP
FROM (SELECT column1, 
             column2,
             column3, 
             column4, 
             SUM(column5) as column5, 
             SUM(column6) as column6, 
             TableB.column7
      FROM TableA 
      LEFT OUT JOIN TableB ON TableB.column7 = TableA.column1
      GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4)
```